# Div with text won't stay inside parent Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

http://goodwell.myshopify.com/collections/all

This is the site I'm working on, but I can't provide any source code as it is a lot and broken into lots of parts as part of the Shopify liquid template.

[image]

Between the first three main picture, there is a small gap in between.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have no gaps between the sections when I resize the browser. There are gaps in between the sections of images (it's very small, like 10px).  I can't figure out  what the issue is for that.

Second, like the title says, I can't figure out why the div with text won't stay inside the parent div.  I would like the text in the div to be centered vertically and horizontally whenever the browser resizes.  I have the horizontal part down but can't figure out the issue with vertical.

Comment: Which div, which text?

Comment: There are so many things that could cause these problems, you need to narrow it down and post the relevant code here if you still have questions.

Comment: The actual effort of creating a small demo of your problem will also likely help you get a better understanding too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited my post with a picture and more explanatory.  The parent div would be homepage-hero, and the child div would be wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was admittedly much harder to find then I thought it would.

[image]

```
.imagefeatured {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Edit:

In the future please be more descriptive with your questions or they may go unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.grid--full {
   position: relative;
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

Looks like the height in this css style is causing those 10px gaps... not sure how to resolve. If you pull out the height property in this style, the gaps disappear.

Comment: Depends on the width.